# Connect UserControlLibrary to WPF application by code

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a project called "Buta".It is like a little operation system.And apps of my project must be in UserControlLibrary and I must attach it with code.When I click button, my usercontrol must be found in path and must be added to my project.That is all.
Thanks...

Comment: If a have mistakes in my question,sorry about it, I'm not English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to build a plugin based architecture for your application? Then you might take a look at MEF. You can find more information at http://mef.codeplex.com/ and an overview at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx